# radgrid insert item and edit items from clientside in 2011.1.519.35

Tags: asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid, radgrid, radgridview

Hi i am using telerik **2011.1.519.35** version

how can i get radgrid insert item and edit items from clientside...
i've used following methods...
but those are not working in version **2011.1.519.35**

```
   function getTableViewInsertItem() {
    var masterTable = $find("<%= RadGrid1.ClientID %>").get_masterTableView();
    //gets the HTML object of the insert item opened in the current GridTableView
    var insertedItem = masterTable.get_insertItem();
    var editedItemsArray = masterTable.get_editItems();
}
```